# The Symbol Relocation

Tags: linker, symbols, relocation

The following is how a function call(for the 1st time) would be resolved in a `PIC`

1. Jump to the `PLT` entry of our symbol.
2. Jump to the `GOT` entry of our symbol.
3. Jump back to the `PLT` entry and push an offset on the stack. That the
   offset is actually an `Elf_Rel` structure describing how to patch the symbol.
4. Jump to the `PLT` stub entry.
5. Push a pointer to a `link_map` structure in order for the linker to
   find in which library the symbol belongs to.
6. Call resolver routine.
7. Patch the `GOT` entry.

This is different from how a data reference is made which just uses the `GOT` table

So, why is there this difference? Why 2 different approaches?

---

Comment: Please don't group unrelated questions. it doesn't cost you extra to ask two separate ones.

Comment: I recently asked a question(related to this topic only) and got no response. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453228/symbol-resolution-and-dynamic-linking

Comment: As far as the second question is concerned I will be making a new post for it as you suggested. Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is there this difference? Why 2 different approaches?

What you described is *lazy* relocation.

You don't *have to* use it, and will not use it if e.g. `LD_BIND_NOW=1` is set in the environment.

It's an optimization: it allows you to reduce the amount of work that the dynamic linker has to perform, when a particular program invocation does not exercise many possible program execution paths.

Imagine a program that can call `foo()`, `bar()` or `baz()`, depending on arguments, and which calls *exactly* one of the routines in any given execution.

If you didn't use lazy relocation, the dynamic loader would have to resolve all 3 routines at program startup. Lazy relocation allows dynamic loader to only perform the one relocation that is actually required in any given execution (the *one* function that is getting called), and at exactly the right time (*when* the function is being called).

Now, why can't *variables* also be resolved that way?

Because there is no convenient way for the dynamic loader to know *when* to perform that relocation.

Suppose the globals are `a`, `b` and `c`, and that `foo()` references `a` and `b`, `bar()` references `b` and `c`, and `baz()` references `a` and `c`. In theory the dynamic loader could scan bodies of `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, and build a map of "if calling `foo`, then also resolve globals `a` and `b`", etc. But it's much simpler and faster to just resolve all references to globals at startup.